# Why does this processing object disappear momentarily after program start?

Tags: processing

This program

```
size(600, 480, P3D);sphere(400);
```

produces the expected object

[image]

but a fraction of a second later, it disappears.

[image]

Why does it disappear?

Note: workaround

```
void setup()
{
  size(100, 100, P3D);
}

void draw()
{
  sphere(100);
}
```

EDIT: With Processing on V3.0.2, Windows 64-bit Pro.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, and does not exhibit the behavior you're describing. What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: 3.02 (added to question). You?

Comment: I'm using Processing 3.1.1. Maybe try updating your Processing version.

Comment: Your code also works fine for me using Processing 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you wrote `sphere()` just next to `size()` tells me that you wrote those lines in `setup()` which is called only once and hence you see the sphere for a split second, for you to see it continuously you need to call `sphere()` in `draw()`

Comment: No. That one-line two-statement program is exactly how I wrote it. No setup().